# Why doesn't numpy 1.14 support savetxt for array with dimension more than 2, while 1.13 seems to support that?

Tags: python, numpy

This difference can be seen in the documentation.

[**1.13 docs**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

> `X` : array_like

[**1.14 docs**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

> `X` : 1D or 2D array_like
>
> Data to be saved to a text file.

Answer (score 3):

> While 1.13 seems to support that

It is not supported in  **`1.13`**. **`1.14`** just improved the error message:

In **`1.13.0`**

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int32') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

In **`1.14.0`**

```
ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 4D array instead
```

Comment: Thanks. I really did not try this, so I said 'seems'. Sorry for this ... I think website of 1.13 can be clearer if stating only 1D or 2D array are supported. Anyway, thanks. (It is probably that I used np.save before when I was using 1.13...)

Answer (score 2):

It never did support arrays of dimension 0 or greater than 2. The docstring and error handling was just improved from 1.13 to 1.14 to better reflect this.

You can see the commit for yourself in the pull request: [ENH: Better error message for savetxt when X.ndim > 2 or X.ndim = 0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9726)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @miradulo. I think it will be better to make some comment in the 1.13 official page, like 'dimension 0 or greater than 2 will not be supported in future version'.

Comment: @JQK It wasn't _previously_ supported either (see the other answer for an example). The change here was strictly an improvement to the error message and docstring.